# avoid showing alert for notification while app is in foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, unusernotificationcenter

hi I used this UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate for avoiding alert notification while app is in foreground with this function

```
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler  API_AVAILABLE(ios(10.0)){
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
}
```

but I get notification with both option Alert & banner 
how can I remove alert while app is in foreground?

Comment: Remove `willPresentNotification` you will not get notification banner and alert in foreground.

Comment: I tried but I will receive alert

Comment: search `willPresentNotification` in your xcode project and comment in every place i have tried and it is working for me.

Comment: It didn't work thanks

Comment: `completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone)` instead?

Comment: hi still alert comes thanks @Larme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to fix there is a option for one signal init to avoid showing alert

```
[OneSignal initWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions appId:@"YOURE_KEY" handleNotificationReceived:nil handleNotificationAction:nil
                            settings:@{kOSSettingsKeyInAppAlerts:@NO}];
```

and for showing as banner you have to add this code

```
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler  API_AVAILABLE(ios(10.0)){
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the condition in the willPresent Method, to check the state of the App, and if State is UIApplecationStateForeGround then do nothing , else they follow UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert .